# Matrices that commute with nonderogatory matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be a nonderogatory $n \times n$ matrix (with complex entries) and let $B$ be a matrix such that $AB=BA$. Show that there exists a polynomial $q(x)$ such that $\sigma(B) = \{ p(\lambda) \mid \lambda \in \sigma(A) \}$.

My approach so far is as follows:

Recall that a matrix is said to be nonderogatory if the geometric multiplicity of each of its eigenvalues is 1 or, equivalently, there is only one Jordan block associated to each eigenvalue in its Jordan canonical form.

Now since $A$ is nonderogatory and $B$ commutes with $A$ there is a polynomial $q(x)$ such that $B=p(A)$. This result can be consulted in *Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson.

My idea is that this polynomial is the desired one. It is easily checked that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $B$. This shows that $\{ p(\lambda) \mid \lambda \in \sigma(A) \} \subseteq \sigma(B)$. Now to prove that equality must hold my idea is to prove that if $\lambda \neq \mu$ are eigenvalues of $A$, then $p(\lambda)\neq p(\mu)$ and that $p(x)$ preserves algebraic multiplicity, but I haven't had much luck so far.

I would appreciate any advice!

Comment: Let $\mu$ be an eigenvalue of $p(A)$. Write $p(X)-\mu=\prod(X-\lambda)$. Then consider what $\det (p(A)-\mu I_n)=0$ implies. What you are after, $\sigma(p(A)=p(\sigma(A))$ is known as the spectral mapping theorem. It is still true in more complicated cases where functional calculus is involved.

Comment: @julien That did the trick! Thank you very much!

Comment: Here is a slightly different point of view, but really the same argument: If A is nonderogatory then all matrices that commute with A have the form
p(A), for some polynomial p. [Ref: M.P. Drazin, J.W. Dungey, K.W. Gruenberg, Some theorems on commutative matrices, J. London Math. Soc. 26 (1951) 221–228.]